# Field with null or empty string value doesn't show up at all in Kafka topic when published

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

When I publish a payload to a kafka topic, if a particular field has a null value, or empty string, then the field doesn’t show up in the payload at all in the kafka topic.  I want the field to still show, with null or empty string value.

For example if I publish a payload with 2 fields, one field named `firstname` and value “`Sara`”, and also another field named `lastname` with a value of `null` or `“”`,  then in the kafka topic there is only the `firstname` field with value “`Sara`”, and there is no `lastname` field displayed at all.  I want `lastname` field to display with value of `null` or `“”`.

Can someone please help me understand why this is happening?  I'm viewing the data through Lenses.io so maybe that UI is simply not showing the null values?  Is there possibly some config to set when configuring the KafkaProducer in my java code, or some config on the Kafka cluster that is causing this?

Comment: I do not think that this has anything to do with Kafka. Can you also enlighten us on what data format you are talking about? A Kafka topic has a key and a value (payload) and also a header so you need to tell us what you mean with the "fields" lastname and firstname.

Comment: firstname and lastname are keys, sarah and null are values

Comment: In JSON, AVRO, other? Remember, "a payload" in Kafka does not have two fields.

Comment: Maybe showing a minimal reproducable code example could help to support you.

Comment: @mike I'm viewing the data through Lenses.io, maybe the lenses ui just doesn't display the fields with null values

Comment: @Artanis - Double check if your data field has `JsonIgnore` property on null or empty. Also you can print payload before publishing to Kafka topic.

Comment: @user370305 my pojo class holding the data field has @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY) but I don't think that would cause it

Comment: Can you try checking using kafka console consumer and verify if the field is coming? If so then it has something to do with Lenses

Comment: @Artanis please share the bean containing firstname, lastname fields?

Comment: Gson / Jackson can be configured in the ObjectMapper to ignore nulls... Do you really need them to be shown? Consumers wouldn't care because they would default to null anyway. If you want an empty string, your class needs to declare the fields that way

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes I believe I needed to adjust the .setSerializationInclusion() method from the object mapper if you want to post the answer

Comment: I wasn't sure of the exact method. Feel free to answer your own post

Answer (score 1):

for Pojo serialization use `@JsonInclude(Include.ALWAYS)` method

for serialization with ObjectMapper use `objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion()` method